# Need help for this case:

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am learning the artificial potential field method for path planning of mobile robot; artificial potential field method has two components: the first one is attractive force and second one is repulsive force. 
The repulsive function is defined as :
[image]
Where Urep is repulsive field, P0 is the distance of influence of the obstacle. P is the distance between the mobile robot and obstacle. ƞ is the proportional coefficient. (X-Xg) is the distance between the mobile robot and goal.  The repulsive force is the negative gradient of this repulsive potential fields function :
[image]

My question is about Frep , what is the difference between Frep1 , Frep2 and ||Frep1|| , ||Frep2||.

Why Frep1 & Frep2 contain parts that rounded with red circles while ||Frep1|| , ||Frep2|| don’t contain?

What is the difference between two states? Could anyone explain that for me?

Thanks in advance

.

.

.

Thanks a lot David, I am really appreciated that for you, thanks for nice explanation, actually the general idea of potential field method is clear to me, the problem which I face is in the repulsive potential field function and specially after taking the negative gradient
I became a little bit confused where in some book I find that  repulsive function in shape of ||Frep1|| , ||Frep2|| is considered and other book the  repulsive function in shape of Frep1 , Frep2 is considered
I need help to understand which one I should considered and why parts that rounded with red circles (which mean partial derivative if I am not wrong) are removed from modules ||Frep1|| & ||Frep2|| and from  Frep1 , Frep2 are not .

Mybe my questions are so silly please forgive I am still beginner.

Thanks

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial X}$ is a notation sometimes used for the gradient; see http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/88935 for example. It produces a vector in general; here it produces unit vectors in the two circled examples. Is there any way you can edit this question to help focus on exactly where the confusion is? (Maybe also a question title that says what the question is about?)

Comment: Thanks a lot David, I am really appreciated that for you, thanks for nice explanation, I added more details about the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think what is going on here is that as the robot moves (as $X$ varies),
$\rho$ can vary, so
$\left(\frac 1\rho - \frac{1}{\rho_0}\right)^2$ is a function of $X$;
and obviously $(X - X_g)^n$ is a function of $X$.
So $U_{rep}$ is the product of a constant and two functions of $X$.

Part of the formula for $F_{rep}$ requires us to find the gradient of $U_{rep}$,
so part of that calculation involves taking the gradient of the product
of two functions.
That is, we apply the product rule, which results in a sum of two terms.
But since the force is actually the negative of the gradient,
we end up with two terms, $F_{rep1}$ and $F_{rep2}$, which are the negatives
of the two terms of the product rule.

The term that eventually becomes $F_{rep1}$, as we further calculate that term
we take a partial derivative of $\frac 1\rho$, which results in a factor
$-\frac{1}{\rho^2}$, but this negative sign cancels the negative sign
from $-grad$ so we end up with no leading negative sign.
For the term that becomes $F_{rep2}$, however, the term in the gradient
has no negative sign, so in taking the negative gradient we have to prefix
a negative sign, as you can see in the expression of $F_{rep2}$.

The gradient is a vector, and so is each of $F_{rep1}$ and $F_{rep2}$.
The factors $\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial X}$ and 
$\frac{\partial(X - X_g)}{\partial X}$ are vectors—in fact, they
are unit vectors—and the other factors in these terms are all scalars.
(Since a potential is a scalar-valued function,
evidently the factor $(X - X_g)^n$ is really $\|X - X_g\|^n$.
Also, while it does not say so explicitly in the excerpted text in the
question, evidently $\eta$ is a positive scalar.)

In general, a vector can be written as the product of the vector's magnitude
(a non-negative scalar) and a unit vector.
For $F_{rep1}$, that unit vector is $\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial X}$,
so if we remove that unit vector we are left with the magnitude of $F_{rep1}$,
written $\|F_{rep1}\|$, sometimes called the modulus of $F_{rep1}$
(or, in the excerpted text in the question, 
it is apparently called the "module" of $F_{rep1}$).
In the case of $F_{rep2}$, we have the product of a magnitude and
the unit vector $-\frac{\partial(X - X_g)}{\partial X}$,
so the magnitude, $\|F_{rep2}\|$, is comprised of all the
other factors of $F_{rep2}$; notice that to write $\|F_{rep2}\|$ we
remove the leading negative sign as well as
$\frac{\partial(X - X_g)}{\partial X}$
from the formula for $F_{rep2}$.